# RDP into google cloud VM instance

Tags: google-compute-engine, rdp

I recently spun up a Windows Server VM instance on google cloud and was able to RDP into it without opening any ports in the firewall.

So, Why am I able to do this? Is it because google opened the port for RDP by default. Also I could n't find any firewall rules that explicilty opened any port.

Thankyou!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The default network](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls#more_rules_default_vpc) comes with ingress rules allowing protocols such as RDP and SSH.
And it  is pre-populated with firewall rules that allow incoming connections to instances. These rules can be deleted or modified as necessary.

- `default-allow-rdp`

It is the rule that allows ingress connections on TCP destination port 3389 from any source to any instance in the network. This rule has a priority of 65534, and it enables connections to instances running the Microsoft Remote Desktop Protocol (RDP).

You could find your default rules on the [Firewall page in the Google Cloud Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/networking/firewalls/list?_ga=2.65380846.1120813285.1607352104-549298192.1605204650&_gac=1.148663877.1607379213.CjwKCAiAwrf-BRA9EiwAUWwKXs96xT84WhL0QBiVkLmROl1-j7OMiZgF9_fG3wrg7DyO4b74YpHFjRoCjlcQAvD_BwE)